# Using a variable from a class to use elsewhere

Tags: c#, .net

I'm fairly new to utilizing classes in C#, so this may seem like a fairly simple question. I am getting an error in my program telling me that *area* (next to Math.Round) does not exist in the current context, so how do I make my *area* variable (from a class) accessible in my Windows Form Code?

Class:

```
class Area
{
    private static double area(double radius)
    {
        return (Math.PI * radius * radius);
    }

    private static double area(int width, int length)
    {
        return (width * length);
    }

    private static double area(double radius, double height)
    {
        return (Math.PI * radius * radius * height);
    }
}
```

Form Code:

```
private void GetCircleAreaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double radius;
        radius = Convert.ToInt32(radiusTextBox.Text);
        circleAreaResultLabel.Text = Math.Round(area(radius), 2).ToString();
    }

    private void GetRectangleAreaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int length, width;
        length = Convert.ToInt32(widthTextBox.Text);
        width = Convert.ToInt32(lengthTextBox.Text);
        rectangleAreaResultLabel.Text = Math.Round(area(length, width), 2).ToString();
    }

    private void GetCylinderAreaButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double radius, height;
        radius = Convert.ToDouble(radiusTextBox.Text);
        height = Convert.ToDouble(heightTextBox.Text);
        cylinderAreaResultLabel.Text = Math.Round(area(radius, height), 2).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: `area` is method, not a variable. To call a static method you should place the class name before it, like `Area.area(radius, height)`. Or add `using static Area` to using directives. And make you methods `public, not `private`

Comment: That seemed to work for the first shape, but 2nd and 3rd one which have 2 arguments (ex. Cylinder has radius and height) gives me an overload error and asks for 2 arguments

Comment: can't reproduce a problem with overload error, your methods is different by argument types and return type, it should be fine until you've passed a parameter with wrong type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `area` is method, not a variable. To call a static method you should place the class name before it, like `Area.area(radius, height)`. Or add `using static Area` to using directives in a file.

And you also have to make all methods `public`, not `private` ones.

Finally, it's a good practice to start a method name from a capital letter, like this

```cs
class Area
{
    public static double GetArea(double radius)
    {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public static double GetArea(int width, int length)
    {
        return width * length;
    }

    public static double GetArea(double radius, double height)
    {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius * height;
    }
}
```

Method overloading allows you to call a `GetArea` method with different parameters and return type

```cs
var circleArea = Area.GetArea(1.1);
var rectrangleArea = Area.GetArea(1, 2);
var cylinderArea = Area.GetArea(1.2, 2.1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an instance of your class.In your case:

```
Area area = new Area();
```

Then you can call say area.area(2,2) etc.

Or alternatively make your class static (this will require making your methods static also because static class can only have static methods.

```
public static class Area
{
    private static double area(double radius)
    {
        return (Math.PI * radius * radius);
    }

    private static double area(int width, int length)
    {
        return (width * length);
    }

    private static double area(double radius, double height)
    {
        return (Math.PI * radius * radius * height);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create an instance to call a `static` method

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make you `area` method public

And because you have static method you can access directly from class name like

```
{
    public static double area(double radius)
    {
        return (Math.PI * radius * radius);
    }

    public static double area(int width, int length)
    {
        return (width * length);
    }

    public static double area(double radius, double height)
    {
        return (Math.PI * radius * radius * height);
    }
}
```

```
Area.area(2) //area(double radius)
Area.area(2,2) //area(int width, int length)
```